# Heroku mysqldump to remote host

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql

I created a nice little Rake task to backup our Mysql database on ClearDB to a remote Google storage bucket. Works great locally but running it on Heroku I get this error:

```
sh: mysqldump: not found
```

Of course, Heroku doesn't have `mysqldump`, how silly of me, but is there any way to do this?

The command I'm using is something like this:

```
system "mysqldump -h host.cleardb.com -u user -p'password' --single-transaction database | gz > #{backup_directory}/#{file_name}"
```

Of course gzip doesn't exist either on Heroku.

I know there are a couple of gems to backup PostgreSQL databases but I haven't seen anything for Mysql.

This is for a Rails 3.2 app.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?  We're skinning this cat now and I'm thinking the best option is to put a bash script that will run the dump on another machine and use something like: exec("ssh [user]@[server] '[command]'")

Comment: I ended up writing a small Ruby rake job that gets called locally from my machine and saves the db to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best option would be a custom build pack that adds the mysql binaries that you need.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to stay away from doing something like that. But thanks for the answer.